# Angularjs run directive after scope has loaded with $http data

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, emit

I need to run a directive that runs a jPager jquery plugin after an http call has loaded the

elements to the DOM.

The jquery is working fine, but I cannot get the directive to run after the screen is rendered (it just runs before and therefore the scope is empty)

I have tried using $emit and $broadcast demo's but still cant get it to fire.

The scope loads

tags into the itemContainer, The jQuery then pages the data.

```
<div wss-pager class="holder"></div>
        <ul id="itemContainer" ng-bind-html="ctData"></ul>

////

function loadData() {
                $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: 'api/getMyData',

                    }).
                    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        // deferred.resolve(data);
                        $scope.ctData = data.m_StringValue;
                    //    
                        $scope.$emit('UpdateJPages');
                    }).
                    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        alert("error" + data);
                        $scope.ctData= "";
                    });

            };

/////////

  angular.module('app').directive("wssPager", [function () {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                    scope.$on('UpdateJPages', function() {

                        $("div.holder").jPages({
                            containerID: "itemContainer",
                            perPage: 5,
                            startPage: 1,
                            startRange: 1,
                            midRange: 5,
                            endRange: 1
                        });


 });
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `ng-if` 
if the cData is empty before this call use like this:

```
<div wss-pager class="holder" ng-if="ctData"></div>
```

If not you can have one extra var e.g. `loaded`

```
<div wss-pager class="holder" ng-if="loaded"></div>
function loadData() {
    $scope.loaded = false;
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'api/getMyData'
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // deferred.resolve(data);
        $scope.ctData = data.m_StringValue;
        $scope.loaded = true
        $scope.$emit('UpdateJPages');
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert('error' + data);
        $scope.ctData= '';
    });
};
```

Comment: This is a simple and clean solution

Comment: This is a much elegant solution than `$scope.$watch`ing or using `$timeout` as the data may fail to load before the timeout runs.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i have found a work around for anyone interested. May not be the best answer but it has solved the issue.

I have used the $timeout function to enable screen to be rendered.

```
 $timeout(function () {
       $scope.$emit('UpdateJPages');
         });
```